# How to dynamically add elements in particular div using jquery. I want to add comment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to create comment system, where entered comments will be added to particular div. below is my code.

```
<ul class="comments">

    <li>
        <a class="commenter_name" href="/">Dushyanth Lion</a>
            comment by user
    </li>
     <li>
         <a class="commenter_name" href="/">Saikat Bhattacharjee</a>
         comment by user
     </li>
</ul>
  <div class="comment_entry">
        <form method="post" action="#">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Leave comment" />
            <input type="submit" style="display:none;" onclick="" />
        </form>
  </div>
```

You can figure out what i am doing here. please tell me how can i dynamically add 'li' after comment is submitted?

Comment: Did you look into this? Appending DOM elements is one of the most fundamental things to do in jQuery, and I can't imagine a Google or SO search wouldn't turn up a plethora of info and examples on this.

Comment: [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: I don't really know how it is connected to backend but using only jQuery it would be something like this `$("ul.comments").append("SOME JS TEMPLATE")`

Comment: append will not work...check with .children() ...

Comment: @CodeJack How do you add elements with `.children()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7rkX4/):

```
var user_name = 'Danil';

$('.comment_entry form').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var comment = $('input', this).val();
  $('.comments').append('<li><a class="commenter_name" href="/">' + user_name + '</a>' + comment + '</li>');
});
```

Comment: Did he/she mean to use jQuery?

Comment: page is reloading afer submitting the form

Comment: page is still reloading after submitting

Comment: yeah thats working, may be i am making some mistake...BTW thanks for your help. accepting your ans :)

Comment: now its working for me..thanks... keep helping other newbies.

Comment: can you help me little more in this.
http://jsfiddle.net/testtracker/7rkX4/1/
this is the same your code but i have added HTML in another div with id=123. can you do something like the id we are writing in javascript will be passed from html like here is id=123, id will be passed to js and comment will be adde to comment block of div with id 123

Comment: there will be many comment box on same page, so in order to add comment in correct box, i want that id will be supplied to js that will recongnise the correct box and add comment in it. now here jsfiddle.net/testtracker/7rkX4/2 box id is "123"...so javascript will add comment in box with id='123' not in any other box..

Comment: let me give you an example, in facebook, when you comment on any post, comment is added to that post only not to other post, so here there will be too many boxes(posts), as we have hardcoded the id in javascript, and there will be '<ul class="comments">' in each post, and it is adding comment to each of those 'ul'...i want comment to be added in same box

Comment: cant we make somthing like we will call a function onsubmit and pass whatever arguments to it, like name of commenter, time of comment.
function addComment(id, name, time){....} something like this

Comment: i want to make somthing like this, so that I can pass arguments like name of commenter etc etc... http://jsfiddle.net/testtracker/7rkX4/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.comments').append('<li><a href="#">Foobar</a> Comment</li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Make submit to normal button and give an id to it as well as to text field:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Leave comment" id="comment" />
<button type="button" style="display:none;" id="submitComment" />
```

Add a jquery :

```
$('#submitComment').live(click,function(){
    $('.comments').append('<a class=\"commenter_name\" href=\"/\">Dushyanth Lion</a>'+ $('#comment').val());
});
```